# Set Length of ComboBox

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to set the length of a Combo Box control in the most efficient way possible. By length, I mean the number of items in the items collection of the Combo Box control.

This is the best attempt I have:

```
    Dim cboNew As New ComboBox
    For i As Integer = 0 To cboSelection.Items.Count - 1
        cboNew.Items.Add(cboSelection.Items(i))
    Next
```

cboSelection is another Combo Box control I have, I am pretty much trying to set the length of cboSelection to cboNew with one line of code (If cboSelection has 5 items, then set cboNew to have 5 items). I feel as if I have done this before, but have forgotten how.

Comment: What is wrong now with this code?

Comment: Code works fine, just looking for an easier method.

Comment: This is pretty much as efficient as it gets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are willing to use the `DataSource` property, you could do something like this:

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ComboBox1.DataSource = New String() {"tony", "bruce", "clark"}
        ComboBox2.DataSource = ComboBox1.DataSource
    End Sub
```